# How to enable anti-aliasing for JavaFX TextField text?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a TextField and a Text object. Both use the exact same font, 
but for the Text object there is a method that can be used to smooth the font: `.setFontSmoothingType()`. However, no such method exists for TextField.

As Shaw pointed out, Text objects by default smooth the font, but this is not the case for TextFields.

This difference is unfortunately noticeable as seen in this screenshot:

[image]

The top is the TextField and the bottom is the Text with smoothing. So how would I smooth the font for the TextField?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hmm, does calling `setFontSmoothingType(FontSmoothingType.GRAY)` actually make a difference? According to [the documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/text/Text.html#fontSmoothingTypeProperty) that's the default value.

Comment: @Slaw you are correct :P I tested it and calling the method doesn't make a difference. Regardless, the text in TextFields is still rendered differently than Text objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was finally able to solve this problem! Using Scene Builder's CSS Analyzer, I was able to find a property called `-fx-font-smoothing-type` under `.text-field .text`. By changing the value to `gray`, the text in the TextField will become smoothed!

[Here's an updated screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPvL9.png)