# Can JavaFx support Linux Gnome Wayland fractional scaling?

Tags: linux, javafx, wayland

I downloaded the latest Open JavaFX SDK, 17.0.2 for x64 Linux, and ran the [sample HelloFX code](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/blob/master/HelloFX/CLI/hellofx/HelloFX.java) using [the instructions](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx). I did not make any changes to them.

The problem is that the text looks blurry if fractional scaling is enabled.Is there an easy way to fix this, or is this a limitation of JavaFX that cannot be fixed until the developers of JavaFX do? (Environment = OpenJDK 18, OpenJfx 17.02, Ubuntu 21.10, Gnome 40.4.0, Wayland)

200%, no fractional scaling
[image]

225%, fractional scaling
[image]

Comment: You may have better luck with this question on the [openjfx-dev mailing list](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/openjfx-dev).

Comment: 1. You should at least mention which JavaFX version you were using. 2. Why do you need this fractional scaling? 225% vs 200% does not sound like such a big difference.

Comment: Have you enabled anti-aliasing? https://stackoverflow.com/q/55584389/1216776

Comment: @mipa I had just clicked the Run button in IntellJ and it automatically somehow prepared JavaFx, so I did not know the exact version. Today, I switched to all manual thing, and downloaded the latest JavaFX from the openjfx.io site. So, the JavaFX version is 17.0.2, and the Java version is 18. I ran the [HelloFX sample code](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/blob/master/HelloFX/CLI/hellofx/HelloFX.java), and it was blurry if fractional scaling is enabled. So, there is no way to avoid this blurriness? As for why I am using 225%, this is just for testing factional scaling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fractional scaling is a wayland only feature and only works with native wayland apps. JavaFX, despite using GTK for things, cannot currently run wayland native and fractional scaling does not work correctly in any XWayland apps. This might change soon but not because of JavaFX wayland support, unfortunately. https://www.phoronix.com/news/GNOME-XWayland-Frac-Scaling